# WinFlash doesn't update Bios when battery is removed

Tags: bios, asus-laptop

I have laptop **ASUS X556UQK**  and it's battery is removed because bloating (Swollen battery).

I'm trying to update Bios from version 312 to 318 using **WinFlash** and the downloaded **Bios file** version 318 from ASUS site.

Here what i did by my side in trying to update the Bios:

1. By following the classic steps to update Bios (throught advanced setup and USB flash), it says `Ez Flash-Check System Power Error: please check battery is connected and remaining capacity is more than 20%.` (this picture is NOT mine but shows the exactly error message https://i.redd.it/63fs58elfkt71.jpg)
2. I tried the alternative methode via terminal

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\WinFlash\WinFlash.exe" /nodate
3. When the system display that i can not update the bios because there is no battery, on my keyboard i type the word "risky".

none of the above steps helped me to update bios without battery or bypass the warning `please check battery is connected and remaining capacity is more than 20%.`

Is there any other way to update my laptop's Bios through WinFlash without battery connected?

Comment: The comment-answer from @LeftCoastSteve explains why you can't flash without the battery inserted and having a charge greater than 20% _(you may already know this, but if not: **do not use your existing battery when it's swollen**, as it means one of the 18650 cells overheated and deformed from the pressure before it was able to be vented. If you still have the battery, iy should be stored in an area that is non-flammable, surrounded by stone/concrete, until taken to a recycling center, as once a Li-Ion battery swells, the electrolyte will leak and if it contacts air, it will burn at ~2,000F)_

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a battery inserted because if you lose power duirng a BIOS update your laptop will become a doorstop. Buy a replacement battery and then you can do the update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But what you said about the (there must be battery plugged) is the opposite of what i saw in youtube and blogs talking about this problem.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't answer the question that was asked. It would make a good comment.